# Is it ok to never release a object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iOS OBJC app, i use a object, specifically a UIImage. I always need this UIImage, specially when the user decides to switch orientations. The problem is I only get this image once and will need it for as long as the app runs. As a result, I have allocted this object and sent it a `retain`. I never release it, because if I do and the user switches orientation, that object could be realsed and I won't be able to do what I need to do and as a result the app will crash.

My Point: What do I do? Is what I'm doing bad because it creates a leak? And if so, how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: (I would argue that *all* memory should be released prior to application-exit -- the lifetime is of course "as long as required" with some caveats on memory pressure. Even if not required it's a good/tidy practice.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're loading a single image once and keeping it around to reuse forever. That is perfectly fine, although if it's a large image that might not be needed constantly you might want to listen for memory notifications and release it then.

Problems with never releasing come in when you allocate large objects or large numbers of objects that are never released. Particularly if you continually re-allocate new instances of the "same" thing because you lose track of the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

John.  I have a different approach, load and release everywhere.  You see, when you use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` **then iOS caches the image**.  Next time you call `[UIImage imageNamed:]`, it uses the cached image, from memory, very quickly. That way you can still code for clean memory (release all over the place, no retain) and iOS has your back.